# Convert python to exe by anaconda

Tags: python, exe, anaconda

I have installed anaconda. How can I convert the .py to .exe **by anaconda only** without the need to install other things like pyInstaller? I cannot easily install other packages in my company

Comment: Convert it at home on your own device!

Answer (score 0):

`pip install auto-py-to-exe`
Install auto-py-to-exe and then 
`auto-py-to-exe`

Answer (score -1):

Check if a python package called py2exe is installed. Try using that.

Comment: No, py2exe is not installed.

Comment: That package needs to be installed in order to convert a python file to .exe